# Rider IDE - Step Backwards

Tags: c#, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, rider

I found out that you can "Step Backwards" in Rider debug by dragging the yellow arrow up.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to "Step Backwards" in Rider IDE?

Answer (score 0):

**For Mac:**

Default KeyMap for back: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

Default KeyMap for forward: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

You can add mapping of your choice by going to Preferences => KeyMap => Then search for back.

**For Windows:**

Default KeyMap for back: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>

Default KeyMap for forward: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right arrow</kbd>